# Import of volume Data from Paraview for physical simulation

Tags: rendering, import

I'd like to ask : how can I import my volume data from Paraview to blender?

Let me preface this with the fact that i just started using blender.

To clarify, what i want to do is this. I have a fluid (smoke) simulation from OpenFoam, that I animated in Paraview, and i wish to recreate the animation using Blender's superior renderer.
So I thought I should export the scene as an x3d file, specifically the density in the "volume" format, and the import it in blender and render it there. But when I do so I don't see anything. If I export the "surface" the exact same way I can see it just fine. Eventually I thought i would export all the frames to 
create an animation, but i cant even see the first frame.
So, what is happening. Is my data format wrong? Should I instead try to import my VTK files instead?

Any help would be appreciated